# QWebView doesn't open links in new window and not start external application for handling pdf

Tags: qt, pdf, window, hyperlink, qwebview

I am using a QWebView in this way:

```
QWebView *window = new QWebView();
window->setUrl(QString("my url"));
window->show();
```

And it works. I can see the html page I want. 
The problem is this. By default if I "right click" on a link the action "Open in new window"  is shown but if I click on it, nothing happens. If I "left click" on the same  link it works.
So the problem is that no new windows are open by QWebView. Does anyone know why?

I have another problem. Some links are pdf file so I expect that QWebView ask me to download it or to run an application to open it. But nothing happens instead. I think the problem is related to the fact that no new windows are allowed to be opened by QWebView and not on the pdf.

Obviously I tested the page with a web browser and everything work well, so the problem is in some settings of QWebView.

Does anyone know how to make QWebView open new windows when required?

Notes:

- all links are local resources.
- The html links use this syntax (and they works):

> ```
>  <a href="./something.htm" TARGET="_parent">Some link</a>
> ```

- The link to pdfs use this syntax (nothing happens when I click):

> ```
> <a href="./pdf/mydoc.pdf" TARGET="pdfwin">Some pdf</a>
> ```

Comment: It seems also, that if you have a `<a href="http://google.com" target="_NEW">Click Me</a>`, you have the same issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to handle cicks by yourself. Here is an example that can guide you. I have not compiled  it though .

```
    QWebView *window = new QWebView();
    window->page()->setLinkDelegationPolicy(QWebPage::DelegateAllLinks);//Handle link clicks by yourself
    window->page()->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::NoContextMenu); //No context menu is allowed if you don't need it
    connect( window, SIGNAL( linkClicked( QUrl ) ),
                  this, SLOT( linkClickedSlot( QUrl ) ) );

    window->setUrl(QString("my url"));
    window->show();

    //This slot handles all clicks    
    void MyWindow::linkClickedSlot( QUrl url )
    {
        if (url.ishtml()//isHtml does not exist actually you need to write something like it by yourself
             window->load (url);
        else//non html (pdf) pages will be opened with default application
            QDesktopServices::openUrl( url );
    }
```

Note that if the HTML you are displaying may containing relative/internal links to other parts of itself, then you should use `QWebPage::DelegateExternalLinks` instead of `QWebPage::DelegateAllLinks`.

Comment: Just correct the second line to:  window->page()->setLinkDelegationPolicy(QWebPage::DelegateAllLinks);

Comment: and isnt it window->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::ContextMenu); ??

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is informative but might be overwhelmed for this question.
Connecting signals to QWebPage::action(OpenLinkInNewWindow) or overriding QWebPage::triggerAction should solve this problem.

Comment: how to implement this "QWebPage::action(OpenLinkInNewWindow)"?